# How to pass parameter value to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parameters

I'm using SqlDataSource to populate a GridView. Here is my code that does that :

```
private void DataCall()
{
    //Object gets created for use from the class(clsDataConduit)
    clsDataDictionary AnOrder = new clsDataDictionary();
    //Declaring a new SqlDataSource from the inbuilt class library
    SqlDataSource sqlDS_ItemTable = new SqlDataSource();
    //Using our datasource object being cast onto our objects connectionstring
    sqlDS_ItemTable.ConnectionString = AnOrder.ConnectionString;
    //Our sql statement being passed through to our .SelectCommand method
    sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectCommand = "Select tblOrders.OrderId, tblItem.ItemName, tblOrders.DateOrdered from tblItem, tblOrders where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId AND tblOrders.AuthId = 5";
    //Adding controls to our SqlDataSource object
    this.Controls.Add(sqlDS_ItemTable);
    //Declares the DataSource for our gridview !
    grdOrder.DataSource = sqlDS_ItemTable;
    //Binds the data to refresh every time it's used
    grdOrder.DataBind();
}
```

As you can see in the SQL statement at the end i'm doing this `tblOrders.AuthId = 5` . However I want to do something like this `tblOrders.AuthId = SessionAuthId .`

I read some posts about doing something alone the lines of `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));` but I don't know how I apply this to my code.

I'm doing this in an assignment using someone elses code (professors) but I want to edit it slightly because i'm going to be developping a login system etc.

Could someone take a look at that method and see how I would change it to pass the parameter to it. Also here is the full code behind : http://pastebin.com/sdrvW5Zn

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Use `string.Format()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Do something like:

```
sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectCommand = string.Format("Select tblOrders.OrderId, tblItem.ItemName, tblOrders.DateOrdered from tblItem, tblOrders where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId AND tblOrders.AuthId = {0}", SessionAuthId);
```

To answer your second question, you would change the signature of the method to include a parameter.

```
private void DataCall(string SessionAuthId)
{
    // your method here...
}
```

Comment: Formatting the string does not add a parameter.  At most, it allows you to use a variable.

Comment: @DanBracuk That's exactly what he is trying to do.  Add a variable to a SQL query.  The method I provided does all the processing on the C# side, instead of in the SQL server.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk This method worked for me and I understood it aswell.

Comment: @Jagga This method is not considered "best practice", it opens you up to SQL Injection attacks, however it is certainly easier.  You should read this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html and this http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/

Comment: Will do! Hopefully by the end of it can use paramaterized version then

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `SelectParameters` property to do a parameterized query.

```
sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectCommand = "Select tblOrders.OrderId, tblItem.ItemName, tblOrders.DateOrdered from tblItem, tblOrders where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId AND tblOrders.AuthId = @authID";

sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@authID", SessionAuthID));
```

Comment: When I used these lines, it highlighted SqlParameter saying it's not an available namespace and also highlighted SessionAuthId saying it's not available in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String authId = SessionAuthID;//pass your session ID to the variable or directly you can     pass this value as the parameter value:

 string strSQL = "Select tblOrders.OrderId, tblItem.ItemName, tblOrders.DateOrdered from   tblItem, tblOrders where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId AND tblOrders.AuthId = @ID";
 SqlCommand cmdItem = new SqlCommand(strSQL, clsMain_Connection.openConn());
 cmdItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", authId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The string.format method suggested by TheGreatCO looks like it would work well for your current implementation where you pass the SQL query as a string.

Otherwise you could create a stored procedure from your SQL snippet and set that up to take parameter.

I am assuming that the sessionAuthId is an int.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SAMPLEPROCEDURENAME

(
    @p1 int      -- here the input parameter is declared
)


AS
    BEGIN

Select 
tblOrders.OrderId, 
tblItem.ItemName, 
tblOrders.DateOrdered 
from tblItem, tblOrders 
where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId 
AND tblOrders.AuthId = @p1   -- here the input parameter is used

END
```

To call the stored proc from c# you need a method like this:

```
public YOURReturnObject PopulateGridView(int sessionid)
{

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourDBConnectionString);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SP_SAMPLEPROCEDURENAME", conn);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",sessionid);

YOURReturnObject o = new YOURReturnObject();

using (comm.Connection)
{
comm.Connection.Open();
while (reader.Read())
{
//read the results into return object 

}
```

}
return o;

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the the "SelectParameters"

```
sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectParameters.Clear(); 
sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectCommand = "Select tblOrders.OrderId, tblItem.ItemName, tblOrders.DateOrdered from tblItem, tblOrders where tblItem.ItemId = tblOrders.ItemId AND tblOrders.AuthId = @authID";
sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectParameters.Add("authID", SessionAuthID);

// sqlDS_ItemTable.SelectParameters.Add("stringParam",  TypeCode.String, stringParam); //like so for string validation
```